# Insert Wordpress shortcode with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, shortcode

I'm really struggeling with the try to output a wordpress shortcode that looks like this:

```
[urlparam attr="value" param="searchpre"]
```

with a js script that dynamically builds a html table on my webpage. The shortcode should be passed out right inside this html element:

```
g='<input type="search" class="'+b.sFilterInput+'" />'
```

Maybe my trying is foolish - i have to add im really a javascript beginner and this would basically be nothing more for me than a cheat to avoid more work and knowledge with javascript in general and about the .js file im trying to manipulate.

Comment: are you place this inside wp editor or in php file?

Comment: where are you calling this shortcode with in a php file or js file?

Comment: its inside a .js file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortcodes are executed with [`do_shortcode()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/) function. And **PHP is executed before Javascript**. So to insert any shortcode with js, you are going to need AJAX.

Comment: this is very helpful - means just inserting the shortcode with a javascript that gets fired after php is basically useless unless there is nothing that starts the process in parts allover again.